# Why are my custom routings colliding with the AccountController / the [Authorize] attribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, .net-core

I am using .Net Core 3.1, Razor Project with a seperate set of "standalone" Controllers. I am also using OIDC for authorization. I've managed to make OIDC work with our company's OAuth2 provider. During that implementation, I've noticed that my custom Routings seem to cause some massive issues with ASP.NET Core's Identity convention. I'll provide a husk example of my Account Controller so the rest of the text makes more sense:

```cs
[Route("api/account")]
    [ApiController]
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("login")]
        public async Task Login(string returnUrl = "/")
        {
            if (!HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                await HttpContext.ChallengeAsync("OpenIdConnect", new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = returnUrl });
            }

            else
            {
                await SetCustomerGuidCookie();
            }
        }

        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("logout")]
        public async Task Logout()
        {
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync("OpenIdConnect",
                new AuthenticationProperties() {RedirectUri = "/"});

            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        }
    }
```

For example, when I tried to configure a controller action for the callback my OIDC provides with a custom routing ("api/account/callback") this would never EVER hit the decorated action in the AccountController above. (Yes, no breakpoint was hit!) (Imagine a Callback action with a Route("callback") attribute.
However, as soon as we put the callback method in another controller, that wasn't the AccountController, for example my UserController, there was no issue at all. Breakpoint was hit, action was doing it's callback stuff.

This is all just a little bit of prefacing to give you some context in what general direction I think the issue is.

---

Now, if I try to protect Razor Pages with the [Authorize] attribute in the model ... (:)

```cs
[Authorize]
    public class RegistrationModel : PageModel
    {
        // some model stuff :)
    }
```

... to my understanding, this should just call the AccountController/Login action.
And, when launching the app, it actually does go to the Action, and somehow generates the correct ReturnUrl!,

```
localhost:5001/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FRegistration
```

but the page just shows 404 and the breakpoint on my AccountController/Login action is not hit.

I tried looking up configurations or information about the [Authorize] attribute and if it's possible to configure the Login route (to my custom route "api/account/login"), but it seems to be deeply nested into the "Convention over configuration" ASP.NET Core 3.1 blackbox.

However, a laced html element in the Razor Views like this:

```cs
<a asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login">Log in</a>
```

or this

```cs
<form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Logout" method="post" id="logout_form"></form>
```

flawlessly go to the AccountController, hit the breakpoints on the actions, and properly do their OAuth stuff.

Comment: Have you tried this already? `[HttpGet("login/{returnUrl}")]` instead of the Route?

Comment: @LegacyCode I just did, and it didn't change the result in the localhost:5001/... snippet. It also broke my login action (2nd to last code snippet), that now does not hit a breakpoint anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We fixed this by changing the custom routing of the AccountController from:

```
[Route("api/account")]
```

to:

```
[Route("account")]
```